# Running process 'as root' with setuid bit not working as expected - operation not permitted?

Tags: unix, permissions, chmod, setuid, linux-capabilities

I have a program that captures network traffic off a network interface. (It's a C program sitting on `libpcap`.)

I'm running Fedora 26.

When I run the program as `root`, things look great:

```
[craig ~]$ sudo su -
[root ~]$ /home/craig/mybinary
(output is as expected)
```

But, when I run the program as myself (`craig`), it fails:

```
[craig ~]$ /home/craig/mybinary
Operation not permitted
[craig ~]$ echo $?
1
```

**What I want** is any user who runs this program to run it "as root". I *think* I set the `setuid` bit and owner/group appropriately:

```
[root@localhost ~]# chmod 6774 /home/craig/mybinary
[root@localhost ~]# ls -lah /home/craig/mybinary
-rwsrwsr--. 1 root  root  1.3M Mar  7  2017 mybinary
```

But the behavior is unchanged - when I run this process as `craig`, it fails with permission-related errors.

Am I missing a step/setting?

Comment: Have you checked if `/home/craig` is not on a filesystem mounted with `nosuid` and for potential interference from SELinux? Furthermore, if the only privileged operations performed by your binary are related to network sniffing, then you do not need full-blown root privileges. Likely `CAP_NET_RAW` (and maybe `CAP_NET_ADMIN`) would be sufficient: `setcap cap_net_raw=ep  /home/craig/mybinary`.

Comment: Try `sudo chmod o+x /home/craig/mybinary`. You need to make sure everyone can execute it. As described in your question only `root.root` has access to execute the file.